# Python: how to document the return value when returning multiple values, using epytext?

Tags: python, docstring, epytext

A simple function:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b
```

How would you document the (multiple) return value using epytext-style?

As a single tuple?

```
def foo():
    """
    This function
    @return (a, b): a tuple of a and b representing...
    """
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b
```

Or with separate `@return` tags for each variable? (is it even "legal"?)

```
def foo():
    """
    This function
    @return a: a int representing...
    @return b: a int representing...
    """
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b
```

Comment: I don't us epytext, but definitely the former. You are returning a tuple of two values, not returning two values. In python's typing, this would be written as `def foo() -> Tuple[int, int]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Python, a tuple literal is created by the comma, not the parens (except for the empty tuple literal `()` which is a bit of a special case), so `return a, b` first creates a `tuple` then returns it. IOW, you are not "returning multiple values" but a single `tuple` object, so the answer is obvious.